# What are some practical reasons to use Zend_Form_Subform other than for multi-page forms?

Tags: zend-framework

I've read the ZF docs regarding subforms, and other than for multi-page form purposes, I'm not sure if I should use zend_form_subform or just have one bigger subform to incorporate all the elements of my form.  Let's say I have a form to create a user object and that there are a few different fieldsets, such as contact information, personal information, and account options.  Is this a good candidate for subforms?  Or would I be overcomplicating things?

Answer (score 1):

Subforms are great for repeating a block of elements, for instance a set of invoice lines, or a customers' shipping and invoicing address.
They also come in handy for multipage forms, in which each page shows a single subform. You can also use it to logically group a number of elements by what they represent. It can make it a lot easier to just extract parts of the form values (for instance only the contact info).

In short; if your form becomes large or complex, it is definitely a good idea to separate it into subforms.

Answer (score 1):

The key argument--and for me only argument--for subforms is validation. You can validate subforms individually and finally the whole form.

If you have similar elements you can easily create a function inside your form class returning an element with preset settings or even create your own element class. If you want to group elements you can do the same, i.e create function or class, but instead you return a displayGroup because that creates the fieldset which you want to present it with in HTML.